# How to load image data into stream and retrieve it out (python 2,7)?

Tags: python-2.7, stream, byte

Im currently trying to imdecode the data in the stream and save it as .jpg format, but i was only manage to imdecode the first image in the stream as the data i retrieve out from stream is the entire stream data.The code below is how i do:

```
import io
import cv2
import numpy as np

f=open('1.jpg','r')
fout=f.read()        //read out the image data
f1=open('2.jpg','r')
f1out=f1.read()
stream.BytesIO()     //create a stream

stream.write(fout)    //write the image data into stream
len(stream.getvalue()) //stream size
image1=np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(),dtype=np.uint8) //retrieve image data 
image1=cv2.imdecode(image1,1)
cv2.imshow('image1',image1)
cv2.waitKey(0)

stream.write(f1out)    //write the image data into stream
len(stream.getvalue()) //stream size increased as 2 images in it
image2=np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(),dtype=np.uint8) //retrieve image data 
image2=cv2.imdecode(image2,1)
cv2.imshow('image2',image2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

i can clearly see that the size of stream is increased after i wrote 2 image data into the stream, but i was only managed to imshow the 1st image but not 2nd image. **stream.getvalue() will get the entire contents of the buffer